# Can you stay in Australia after your work visa expires, if you also have a valid tourist visa (class 600)?

Tags: visas, australia, russian-citizens, transition-of-visa-status

Assuming one has a working visa in Australia (class 457) and a valid tourist visa (class 600), can they combine the two stays by staying past the work visa's expiration date? Or would you need to fly out of Australia and return in order to 'activate' the tourist visa?

Same question applies for executing the 'change of status' in the other direction - flying into Australia on a tourist visa *before* your work visa begins.

[Related Expats question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/10257/when-applying-for-an-australian-temporary-worker-visa-457-how-can-you-get-ext)

Comment: There's another possibility. There could be a process for a formal application for change of status while remaining in the country. Such a process exists in many countries, though I do not know whether it exists in Australia.  This seems like an [Expatriates.SE] question, though.

Comment: @phoog there is an option to get a tourist visa while inside Australia, but it seems easier to me to have everything done in advance. The contract will be for only 6 months and who knows how long it would take to get a 'tourist' extension.

Comment: If the Australian rules are the same as other countries' rules I'm familiar with, you need to leave the country or to apply formally for the change of status, but if you do the latter and then leave before the change is approved then you are essentially in compliance, so the fact that the status change might take months is not particularly problematic.

Comment: @phoog there is also the issue of 'pre-padding' - entering Australia before on a tourist visa before the work visa. I will expand the question now.

Comment: Do you have Condition 8503 (no further stay, that is you cannot apply for another visa in Australia) on your Class 457 authorization?

Comment: @SheikPaul I don't have the 457 yet. Planning for the future for now, pre application.

Comment: Under [Australian law](https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/C2016C01111/Html/Volume_1#_Toc466969645), you can only have one visa at a time.  When you are granted the 457 visa, your existing visitor visa will cease to have effect.

Comment: @k2moo4 what if the visas are back to back?

Comment: @JonathanReez If you are physically in Australia when the 457 visa is granted (e.g. on a prior tourist visa), then the 457 visa commences immediately and the existing tourist visa ceases to have effect.  If you are outside Australia when the 457 visa is granted, then it commences on the date specified on the visa, in which case the tourist visa will still be valid until that date.

Comment: @k2moo4 let's say my 457 is issued until December 31st and my 600 was from January 1st. Would the 600 immediately become invalid?

Comment: @JonathanReez It depends on when the visa is granted, when the visa takes effect (i.e. when it starts), and when it ends.  With some minor exceptions, when a visa starts, all existing visas cease to have effect.  Some visas take effect immediately on grant (which automatically invalidates other visas), whereas other may start on some other date or event (e.g. when you arrive).  You should check the terms of each visa carefully to avoid accidentally invalidating them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Confirmed YES you can change from class 457 visa to a tourist visa. Someone did it [before](http://www.australiaforum.com/visas-immigration/6076-457-tourist-visa-defacto.html). *Scroll to last posting at bottom of page in link*.

However you have to apply for the change, not just combine it by yourself. If approved you would not need to fly out and return to *activate* it.

Per [Department of Immigration and Border Protection’s (DIBP)](http://www.border.gov.au/Lega/Lega/Form/Immi-FAQs/how-can-i-extend-my-stay),

> If you want to stay in Australia longer than your original visa lets
>   you, you will need to apply for a further visa of the same kind **or
>   another visa**. How much longer you can stay in Australia will depend
>   on the visa that you have, or the visa that you apply for. **If you
>   have a ‘No further stay’ condition on your visa, you cannot apply for
>   a new visa while you are in Australia**.

To change the type of visa you have in Australia, you will need to contact the Department of Immigration and Citizenship at least 14 days before your current visa expires. You might be granted a new visa if you fulfil all requirements and you have followed the rules of your current visa. [Source](https://auvisa.org/uk/evisitor-visa-australia/)

In reality immediately you make that application, you would automatically be deemed to have applied for a [bridging visa](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/010-) so you maintain legal status while your petition is adjudicated. You should however still be in good status with your current 457 to be eligible.

Best

Comment: But what if I *already* have a 600 (tourist) visa? Do you still have to apply for one and fly out?

Comment: @JonathanReez Reread my answer. I never said that. You need approval to **SWITCH** to it.