# Can I apply for Australia tourist visa (600) when I hold Temporary Skill Shortage (subclass 482)? Will it overwrite my existing Visa?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australia

"___ currently holds a valid visa for travel to Australia. If a visa is granted as a result of this application it will replace the visa currently held by the applicant. The applicant should check their current visa details and conditions via Visa Entitlement Verification Online (VEVO) on our website, before continuing with this application. This will help the applicant to confirm that the visa being applied for is more beneficial than the visa currently held"

Comment: My start of onshore work has postponed. Meanwhile I wish to have a vacation in Australia and meet my family who is on PR. One of the condition says You must start work within 90 days of:
• arriving in Australia, if you were outside Australia when the visa was granted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, you can only hold only one Australian visa at a time.  While you can apply for a Visitor (subclass 600) visa while you are holding a Temporary Skill Shortage (subclass 482) visa, if your application is approved, **your Visitor visa will "overwrite" your Temporary Skill Shortage visa** (see [subsection 82(2) of the *Migration Act 1959*](https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/C2019C00289/Html/Volume_1#_Toc20145306)), and you will lose your work rights.

Comment: Is there any way I can travel as tourist on my 482?

Comment: @user1979730 See the answer to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/98627/holidaying-prior-to-start-of-a-sponsored-australian-work-visa). Note you must comply with the condition of working in your sponsored job within 90 days of your first arrival.